# Ruby: trying to run set command

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

I am working with Chef and ruby and I am trying to run the set command.

```
setVarList = %x(set)
```

If I just type set it works fine, but if I run this script I get the following error:

```
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/motd/recipes/default.rb:22: command not found:   set
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `setVarList = %x(/bin/bash -c set)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Anew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/955526/anew) already mentioned: **set** is bash built in command, but ruby %x() shell is **sh**.

```
%x(echo $0)
```

The workaround is running bash explicitly, as proposed by [CodeGnome](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1301972/codegnome) in comment.

```
%x(/bin/bash -c set)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're not spawning a `bash` shell.

`set` is a bash builtin:

> 4.3.1 The Set Builtin
>
> This builtin is so complicated that it deserves its own section. set allows you to change the values of shell options and set the positional parameters, or to display the names and values of shell variables.

```
set
set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [-o option-name] [argument …]
set [+abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [+o option-name] [argument …]
```

> If no options or arguments are supplied, set displays the names and values of all shell variables and functions, sorted according to the current locale, in a format that may be reused as input for setting or resetting the currently-set variables. Read-only variables cannot be reset. In POSIX mode, only shell variables are listed.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

Try running `ps -p $$` to see which shell is getting spawned.

```
anew@Wintermute:~$ ps -p $$
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
10018 ttys001    0:00.11 -bash
anew@Wintermute:~$
```

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information! If I could upvote, you would have had one.